# Network Unreachable For Ethernet Interface Arch Linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, configuration, network-interface, ethernet

Everything was working fine up until today, I've been fiddling for hours trying to configure ethernet on my arch install with no luck. I run a dual boot system with windows and networking seems to be working fine there.

No matter what I tried every time I tried to ping an address I just got "network unreachable"

I tried booting from a live CD made using the same ISO that I used to make my install in the first place. That doesn't seem to want to connect either (although it worked fine when I used it to make my installation)

Following through the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration) I get the following outputs.

### lspci -v

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
...
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

### dmesg | grep r8169

```
[    4.489078] libphy: r8169: probed
[    4.489584] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl, 50:e5:49:44:08:b9, XID 2c900800, IRQ 34
[    4.489586] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    4.493645] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.360274] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
```

From what I can gather this means the kernel driver has been loaded

### ip link show dev enp4s0

```
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 50:e5:49:44:08:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Interface seems to be up but when I run dhcpcd I get an error

### sudo dhcpcd enp4s0

```
enp4s0: waiting for carrier
timed out
dhcpcd exited
```

I also tried using the example ethernet-dhcp and ethernet-static configs with netctl (changing eth0 to enp4s0 for each config) then enabling and starting them with "netctl enable ethernet-xxx" and "netctl start ethernet-xxxx". That didn't return any errors but I still get "network unreachable".

Answer (score 1):

Interface is down and has no carrier. check cabling (NO-CARRIER and state DOWN show this).

what does ifconfig enp4s0 up say?

Comment: Networking is fine on my windows partition and I've already tried changing the cable (the onboard lan is also my only network device). And I did set the interface to up using "sudo ip link set enp4s0 up" without any error.

Comment: From what I can tell you, the r8169 driver will not work, but the r8168 will do. I had this problem also some time ago and had to compile a driver by myself (trying to upgrade your kernel may work also. https://medium.com/@lgobinath/no-ethernet-connection-in-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18-with-realtek-rtl8111-8168-8411-7ae2779dc9b8 is a reference there

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try compiling the r8168 driver manually though I don't think it's a kernel issue somehow since all arch live CD's I've tried have all loaded the same driver and refused to work including the one that worked when I first installed Arch

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with something in the bios that a recent failed overclock must have reverted.

I'm not exactly sure what the BIOS setting that was causing the issue was as I just reverted back to my preset but someone from [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4rgp7a/eth0_nocarrier_on_archwired_connection_not_working/) suggested to check the PXE setting.